# Based on a condition how to assign output to a variable matching types

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to modify a library that uploads asynchronous a file so that it can "expose" or "notify" in what iteration it is, my goal is to prevent "printing/writing" from the library directly and instead do it from the methods that use the library so that by using the "exposed" data they could do something. The code I am using for testing a task in every interaction is:

```
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};

let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new())
    .inspect_ok(|chunk| {
        // do X with chunk...
    });

// reqwest
let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
client.put(url).body(body)
```

I am thinking of using a channel to "share the state" (if this could be called this way) so that if I receive a `Sender` as an argument I could write to it and from the method that is making the call, use the `Receiver` to do something (display progress bar for example), this is what I am trying:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc; 

fn upload(file: String, sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<usize>) {
    let stream = if let Some(mut tx) = sender {
        FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new()).inspect_ok(move |chunk|
             tx.send(chunk.len())
        )
    } else {
        FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new())
    };

    // reqwest
    let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
    client.put(url).body(body)
    let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
`if` and `else` have incompatible types
```

I also tried:

```
let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new());

if let Some(mut tx) = sender {
    stream.inspect_ok(move |chunk|
         tx.send(chunk.len())
    );
}
```

But get `mismatched types`

How could this be implemented? any better approaches to channels?

For example, I would like to use the crate [indicatif](https://crates.io/crates/indicatif) something like this:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use indicatif::ProgressBar;  
use mylibrary::upload; 

let (mut tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(100);

let bar = ProgressBar::new(1000);
 
// here pass the sender so that in the receiver i could increment the progress bar
let response = upload("file", Some(tx));

while let Some(i) = rx.recv().await {
   bar.inc(1);
}

bar.finish();
```

Comment: my idea is to give as an option the `Sender`  if there is  `None` simply just upload the `stream` : `let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);` the "developer" using the library if want to get the  "state" should pass as an argument `Some(sender)` maybe there are better ways of doing this any advice is more than welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the body within the `if` in order that both arms have type `Body`:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

fn upload(file: String, sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<usize>) {
    let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new());

    let body = if let Some(mut tx) = sender {
        Body::wrap_stream(stream
            .inspect_ok(move |chunk| tx.send(chunk.len()))
        )
    } else {
        Body::wrap_stream(stream)
    };

    // not sure where `client` or `url` are defined?
    client.put(url).body(body)
}
```

Or, per [@SvenMarnach's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374041/based-on-a-condition-how-to-assign-output-to-a-variable-matching-types/63374116?noredirect=1#comment112064489_63374116):

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use futures::future::Either;

fn upload(file: String, sender: Option<mpsc::Sender<usize>) {
    let stream = FramedRead::new(file, BytesCodec::new());

    let stream = if let Some(mut tx) = sender {
        Either::Left(stream
            .inspect_ok(move |chunk| tx.send(chunk.len()))
        )
    } else {
        Either::Right(stream)
    };

    let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);

    // not sure where `client` or `url` are defined?
    client.put(url).body(body)
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, wrap the two streams in the branches of the `if let` expression in [`Either::Left` and `Either::Right`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/future/enum.Either.html). The `Either` enum implements the `Stream` trait if the left and the right type implement `Stream` with identical item types.